# android get vibration settings

Tags: android, setting, vibration

I need to get the right settings for vibrator so that my application respects the device's sound settings. On the following code, if the vibrator is off(on my phone when I lower the volume, it is a state when the volume is off and vibrator is off and one when volume is off an vibrator is on). When the phone is set to no vibrate (verified by making a call to this device), I still get the vibrator as being on:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) PingerApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int vibrationSetting = audioManager.getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
boolean vibrate;
switch(vibrationSetting) {
case AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON:
    vibrate = true;
    break;
case AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF:
    vibrate = false;
    break;
case AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT:
    vibrate = (audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    break;
default:
    vibrate = false;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? vibrationSetting is always `AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON`

Answer (score 2):

You can also put check on AudioManager.getRingerMode(), e.g.

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
    {
        // should not vibrate
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc, you should use `AudioManager.shouldVibrate(int)` instead.